# Trying to use Array Methods when type is an Array Union Type

Tags: typescript

I'm refactoring an Angular application so we can turn on strict typing.

I'm having an issue using array methods with an array union type in our LookupService.  When I try to invoke `const lookup = lookupConfig.find(l => l.code === code);` it shows an error of:

> This expression is not callable.
> Each member of the union type '{ <S extends Lookup>(predicate: (this: void, value: Lookup, index: number, obj: Lookup[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S | undefined; (predicate: (value: Lookup<...>, index: number, obj: Lookup<...>[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): Lookup<...> | undefined; } | { ...; } | { ...; }' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.

I've been playing around with several solutions that I found in Github issues and StackOverflow, but I can't seem to find a way to accomplish this where I don't have to create a new method for each existing (and future) union like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55080924/1148107) outlines.

I created a [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4&ssl=22&ssc=29&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgDIHt0GsCuAHAHgBVkIAPSEAEwGdkQcBbAI2mQB9kawpQBzZAF56TVlAB8yAN4BYAFDJFyBOioQAXMiIBueUvpxGGrj3665AX3nzQkWIhQAFKOgBuoJBmz5SFCNTovXEJuXhA+SVkFZXQccCgATwBhVWNQs3krORtwaHgkNExglJAYYAEoxRUAG2qIPmMg-ABtAF1zKtj44AgaTSaQ03DxNo7kPBd3ECQ+5Gc3DwgB0czrORUQbmRqovwSsr5+3cIGFmgR1o5C70GwiLar+anPY4fhFey5GDiEMGB0EDIBpgAbEXyUWgiM5QK7pYYAChUak0RAAlNI9MgoBAwDgoICdjd9uUAHRlajw+HVI43YjidGCSTVElIlCCdkxNSo8wWczyDZbbE0HDVMBCIE4gbwgCM3KAA) or you can see it below:

```js
interface Lookup<T extends number | string = number> {
    code: T;
    name: string;
}

interface ProvinceLookup extends Lookup<string> {
  countryCode: string;
}

interface LookupConfig {
  college: Lookup[];
  countries: Lookup<string>[];
  provinces: ProvinceLookup[];
}

const lookupConfig: Lookup<number>[] | Lookup<string>[] | ProvinceLookup[] = [];

function getLookup<T extends number | string>(code: T) {
  return lookupConfig.find((l: Lookup<T>) => l.code === code);
};

const result = getLookup(1);
```

Actual implementation where `find` is showing the error:

```js
private lookupValue<T extends string | number>(
  lookupCode: T,
  lookupKey: string,
  key: string
): unknown | null {
  const lookupConfig = this.lookupService[lookupKey as keyof LookupConfig];
  const lookup = lookupConfig?.find((l: Lookup) => l.code === lookupCode);

  return lookup && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(lookup, key)
    ? lookup[key]
    : null;
}
```

Comment: If you are only going to access the `code`-property, you could do some typecasting in the `getLookup` function like so: `(lookupConfig as ({code: string | number})[]).find(l => l.code === code);`

Answer (score 0):

I abused/exploited the fact that each lookup inherits from Lookup so I could keep working based on @arno-van-liere's comment.  Even though different lookups have keys that exist that aren't on Lookup (like `countryCode` on provinces) the property check using `hasOwnProperty` provides safety that the property does exist even though the property access typing is a lie.

If anyone has a better solution that is type safe I would def make changes, but for now I've commented above the return in code that it isn't accurate:

```js
private lookupValue<T extends number | string>(
  lookupCode: T,
  lookupKey: string,
  key: string
): unknown | null {
  const lookupConfig = this.lookupService[lookupKey as keyof LookupConfig];
  const lookup = (lookupConfig as Lookup<T>[])?.find(
    (l: Lookup<T>) => l.code === lookupCode
  );

  return lookup && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(lookup, key)
    ? lookup[key as keyof Lookup<T>]
    : null;
}
```